# Check for Every Ajax is loaded in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax

I have a asp.net page with one Jquery file. Whenever the page is loading around 10 Ajax calls are called and the data is populated to dropdowns and Data grids. I have a save button in the page. Is there any way that I can block the UI or Disable the save button until every ajax call is Executed and loaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ajaxStop` event. [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/).

Answer (score 0):

Ajax call provide you the feature for the call back function. I think you can set the counter in the callback function that get increment its value by each call's response when your counter is reached to the required number then enable the save button.

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko, Thanks for the comment. I learn new things from Stack overflow, but I don't stop sharing my answer by caring about it. If I would have cared about it then I would have stopped the answering the questions :-) 

BTW, thanks I learnt something from your answer. ;-)

Comment: Didn't mean to be offensive or something. But adding a callback to every place you are making a request sounds like a bad idea from the very beginning :)